# Json Deserialize in multiple Java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I try to deserialize json :

```
{
"date": "2021_05",
"uuid": "3ba8b966-993f-49e0-b349-e528843a382c",
"dataset": "dataset",
"hmm_hit": "hit",
"hmm_evalue": "6.7e-186",
"hmm_score": "610.9"  
},
```

I have two entities :

```
@Entity
public class HmmResult {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @JsonIgnore
 private Integer id;

 @JsonProperty("hmm_hit")
 private String hmm;

 @JsonProperty("hmm_evalue")
 private String eValue;

 @JsonProperty("hmm_score")
 private Float score;
 }
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Protein {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;

    @JsonProperty("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @JsonProperty("dataset")
    private String dataset;

   @OneToOne
   @JsonDeserialize(as = HmmResult.class)
   private HmmResult hmmResult;
```

How to deserialize both entities at the same time with one entry of json ?
Here is extract of main with Jackson ObjectMapper :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            Protein p = objectMapper.readValue(new File(file), Protein.class);
```

It parses "date", "uuid" and "dataset" fine but can not parse HmmResult object with "hmm_subfamily", "hmm_evalue" and "hmm_score" values : I get error : p.getHmmResult() : null.  (HmmResult hm = objectMapper.readValue(new File(file), HmmResult.class); works fine too alone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation for this. Should work like this:

```
public class Protein {
   @JsonProperty("date")
   private String date;

   @JsonProperty("uuid")
   private String uuid;

   @JsonProperty("dataset")
   private String dataset;

   @JsonUnwrapped
   private HmmResult hmmResult;
}

var protein = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(file), Protein.class);
```